# How can I make the height of an element cover more than the visible area of the window?

Tags: css

I try to make the complete height of an element with absolute position and relative to body extend to the top of the whole page including the space that is not seen. only when scrolling

In the example, the sidebar extends along the visible view of the window, if the user scrolls the space that is not covered is noted

How can I make the height of an element cover more than the visible area of the window?

Thanks in advance

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid darkturquoise;
}

nav.menu {
    background-color: deeppink;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

nav.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="items">
      <li>item-1</li>
      <li>item-2</li>
      <li>item-3</li>
      <li>item-4</li>
      <li>item-5</li>
      <li>item-6</li>
      <li>item-7</li>
      <li>item-8</li>
      <li>item-9</li>
      <li>item-10</li>
      <li>item-11</li>
      <li>item-12</li>
      <li>item-13</li>
      <li>item-14</li>
      <li>item-15</li>
      <li>item-16</li>
      <li>item-17</li>
      <li>item-18</li>
      <li>item-19</li>
      <li>item-20</li>
      <li>item-21</li>
      <li>item-22</li>
      <li>item-23</li>
      <li>item-24</li>
      <li>item-25</li>
      <li>item-26</li>
      <li>item-27</li>
      <li>item-28</li>
      <li>item-29</li>
      <li>item-30</li>
      <li>item-31</li>
      <li>item-32</li>
      <li>item-33</li>
      <li>item-34</li>
      <li>item-35</li>
      <li>item-36</li>
      <li>item-37</li>
      <li>item-38</li>
      <li>item-39</li>
      <li>item-40</li>
      <li>item-41</li>
      <li>item-42</li>
      <li>item-43</li>
      <li>item-44</li>
      <li>item-45</li>
      <li>item-46</li>
      <li>item-47</li>
      <li>item-48</li>
      <li>item-49</li>
      <li>item-50</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: nav.menu {positon:fixed;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the height of your menu to `100%` and give the body a `position: relative;`

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid darkturquoise;
}

nav.menu {
    background-color: deeppink;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

nav.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="items">
      <li>item-1</li>
      <li>item-2</li>
      <li>item-3</li>
      <li>item-4</li>
      <li>item-5</li>
      <li>item-6</li>
      <li>item-7</li>
      <li>item-8</li>
      <li>item-9</li>
      <li>item-10</li>
      <li>item-11</li>
      <li>item-12</li>
      <li>item-13</li>
      <li>item-14</li>
      <li>item-15</li>
      <li>item-16</li>
      <li>item-17</li>
      <li>item-18</li>
      <li>item-19</li>
      <li>item-20</li>
      <li>item-21</li>
      <li>item-22</li>
      <li>item-23</li>
      <li>item-24</li>
      <li>item-25</li>
      <li>item-26</li>
      <li>item-27</li>
      <li>item-28</li>
      <li>item-29</li>
      <li>item-30</li>
      <li>item-31</li>
      <li>item-32</li>
      <li>item-33</li>
      <li>item-34</li>
      <li>item-35</li>
      <li>item-36</li>
      <li>item-37</li>
      <li>item-38</li>
      <li>item-39</li>
      <li>item-40</li>
      <li>item-41</li>
      <li>item-42</li>
      <li>item-43</li>
      <li>item-44</li>
      <li>item-45</li>
      <li>item-46</li>
      <li>item-47</li>
      <li>item-48</li>
      <li>item-49</li>
      <li>item-50</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found 4 solutions with a slight different behavior and approachs.

**First Solution**

make your `nav` container (`body` in your case) `position: relative`, it will make sense of `nav` `position: absolute` and now you can choose to make `nav's` `height: 100%` or `bottom: 0`.

*Disadvantage* - menu scrolls with items.

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid darkturquoise;
}

nav.menu {
    background-color: deeppink;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

nav.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="items">
      <li>item-1</li>
      <li>item-2</li>
      <li>item-3</li>
      <li>item-4</li>
      <li>item-5</li>
      <li>item-6</li>
      <li>item-7</li>
      <li>item-8</li>
      <li>item-9</li>
      <li>item-10</li>
      <li>item-11</li>
      <li>item-12</li>
      <li>item-13</li>
      <li>item-14</li>
      <li>item-15</li>
      <li>item-16</li>
      <li>item-17</li>
      <li>item-18</li>
      <li>item-19</li>
      <li>item-20</li>
      <li>item-21</li>
      <li>item-22</li>
      <li>item-23</li>
      <li>item-24</li>
      <li>item-25</li>
      <li>item-26</li>
      <li>item-27</li>
      <li>item-28</li>
      <li>item-29</li>
      <li>item-30</li>
      <li>item-31</li>
      <li>item-32</li>
      <li>item-33</li>
      <li>item-34</li>
      <li>item-35</li>
      <li>item-36</li>
      <li>item-37</li>
      <li>item-38</li>
      <li>item-39</li>
      <li>item-40</li>
      <li>item-41</li>
      <li>item-42</li>
      <li>item-43</li>
      <li>item-44</li>
      <li>item-45</li>
      <li>item-46</li>
      <li>item-47</li>
      <li>item-48</li>
      <li>item-49</li>
      <li>item-50</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

**Second Solution**

make `nav` `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` or `height: 100%` or `height: 100vh`.

In this case menu is always visible when items are scrolling.

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid darkturquoise;
}

nav.menu {
    background-color: deeppink;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 80px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

nav.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="items">
      <li>item-1</li>
      <li>item-2</li>
      <li>item-3</li>
      <li>item-4</li>
      <li>item-5</li>
      <li>item-6</li>
      <li>item-7</li>
      <li>item-8</li>
      <li>item-9</li>
      <li>item-10</li>
      <li>item-11</li>
      <li>item-12</li>
      <li>item-13</li>
      <li>item-14</li>
      <li>item-15</li>
      <li>item-16</li>
      <li>item-17</li>
      <li>item-18</li>
      <li>item-19</li>
      <li>item-20</li>
      <li>item-21</li>
      <li>item-22</li>
      <li>item-23</li>
      <li>item-24</li>
      <li>item-25</li>
      <li>item-26</li>
      <li>item-27</li>
      <li>item-28</li>
      <li>item-29</li>
      <li>item-30</li>
      <li>item-31</li>
      <li>item-32</li>
      <li>item-33</li>
      <li>item-34</li>
      <li>item-35</li>
      <li>item-36</li>
      <li>item-37</li>
      <li>item-38</li>
      <li>item-39</li>
      <li>item-40</li>
      <li>item-41</li>
      <li>item-42</li>
      <li>item-43</li>
      <li>item-44</li>
      <li>item-45</li>
      <li>item-46</li>
      <li>item-47</li>
      <li>item-48</li>
      <li>item-49</li>
      <li>item-50</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

**Third Solution**

you can change structure.

Make some `wrapper` of `menu` and `container`. Move `menu` above `container`. Make `wrapper` `display: flex`. You can remove `position: absolute` and `top: 0` from `menu`.

As in first solution - `menu` scrolls with items.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid darkturquoise;
}

nav.menu {
  background-color: deeppink;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
}

nav.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="items">
      <li>item-1</li>
      <li>item-2</li>
      <li>item-3</li>
      <li>item-4</li>
      <li>item-5</li>
      <li>item-6</li>
      <li>item-7</li>
      <li>item-8</li>
      <li>item-9</li>
      <li>item-10</li>
      <li>item-11</li>
      <li>item-12</li>
      <li>item-13</li>
      <li>item-14</li>
      <li>item-15</li>
      <li>item-16</li>
      <li>item-17</li>
      <li>item-18</li>
      <li>item-19</li>
      <li>item-20</li>
      <li>item-21</li>
      <li>item-22</li>
      <li>item-23</li>
      <li>item-24</li>
      <li>item-25</li>
      <li>item-26</li>
      <li>item-27</li>
      <li>item-28</li>
      <li>item-29</li>
      <li>item-30</li>
      <li>item-31</li>
      <li>item-32</li>
      <li>item-33</li>
      <li>item-34</li>
      <li>item-35</li>
      <li>item-36</li>
      <li>item-37</li>
      <li>item-38</li>
      <li>item-39</li>
      <li>item-40</li>
      <li>item-41</li>
      <li>item-42</li>
      <li>item-43</li>
      <li>item-44</li>
      <li>item-45</li>
      <li>item-46</li>
      <li>item-47</li>
      <li>item-48</li>
      <li>item-49</li>
      <li>item-50</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fourth Solution**

structure as in the third solution.

But we make `menu` with `position: sticky`, `top: 0` and `height: calc(100vh - 10px * 2);` (10px top and bottom padding value, if not subtract menu scrolls a little bit at the bottom of items scroll)

Menu is always visible.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul.items li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid darkturquoise;
}

nav.menu {
  background-color: deeppink;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 10px * 2); /*top + bottom padding value*/
}

nav.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="items">
      <li>item-1</li>
      <li>item-2</li>
      <li>item-3</li>
      <li>item-4</li>
      <li>item-5</li>
      <li>item-6</li>
      <li>item-7</li>
      <li>item-8</li>
      <li>item-9</li>
      <li>item-10</li>
      <li>item-11</li>
      <li>item-12</li>
      <li>item-13</li>
      <li>item-14</li>
      <li>item-15</li>
      <li>item-16</li>
      <li>item-17</li>
      <li>item-18</li>
      <li>item-19</li>
      <li>item-20</li>
      <li>item-21</li>
      <li>item-22</li>
      <li>item-23</li>
      <li>item-24</li>
      <li>item-25</li>
      <li>item-26</li>
      <li>item-27</li>
      <li>item-28</li>
      <li>item-29</li>
      <li>item-30</li>
      <li>item-31</li>
      <li>item-32</li>
      <li>item-33</li>
      <li>item-34</li>
      <li>item-35</li>
      <li>item-36</li>
      <li>item-37</li>
      <li>item-38</li>
      <li>item-39</li>
      <li>item-40</li>
      <li>item-41</li>
      <li>item-42</li>
      <li>item-43</li>
      <li>item-44</li>
      <li>item-45</li>
      <li>item-46</li>
      <li>item-47</li>
      <li>item-48</li>
      <li>item-49</li>
      <li>item-50</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```